# Excel VBA not working when "enable editing"

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'm not sure if this is the right place to post this but I'm having issues with excel VBA. I sent a worksheet with custom VBA attached to an email. Once the user downloads the file, it open in excel in "protected view" and a button "enable editing" is shown. Once that is clicked, all the VBA code is deleted. Is there anyway to get around this?

Comment: I have experienced this with virus scanners before.  Auto run macros are suspected of being viruses.  I have got round it by changing the extension to something like "DAT".  The user saves the workbook, restores the extension and the macro will run when the workbook is opened.

Comment: What is the version of excel you are using and what is the extension of the file you sent?

Comment: @TonyDallimore - You should repost your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As *@TonyDallimore* said in his comment, you can get around this problem by changing the extension of file attached to your email.

I would suggest saving the Excel file as **"*.xlsb"*** (i.e. binary file) which later the user can change it to **"*.xlsm"*** or even be used it as is. However, still some virus scanners may catch that too. In that case, changing the extension to something random like **"*.txt"*** would be safer but make it a little bit laborious or maybe complicated for not skilled users to figure out what have you sent and what they should do to get it work as expected.

Zipping into multiple layers (zip to **"*.RAR"*** and then again to **"*.zip"***) may work too.